# Nginx fails to create a log file (without errors)

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, logging

I'm following [AWS's instructions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/health-enhanced-serverlogs.html) to enable enhanced health monitoring for elastic beanstalk. As part of that, I need nginx to output a log file into `/var/log/nginx/healthd` named accordingly: `application.log.YYYY.MM.DD.HH`.

For some reason, my nginx won't create the file. It is able to create `application.log` or `aplication.log.1-2-3-4` in that folder, but not `application.log.YYYY.MM.DD.HH`. It just doesn't appear. No errors or anything.

My nginx conf:

```
worker_processes        auto;
error_log               /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid                     /var/run/nginx.pid;
worker_rlimit_nofile    32634;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [[$time_local]] "$request" '
                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';
    log_format healthd '$msec"$uri"'
            '$status"$request_time"$upstream_response_time"'
            '$http_x_forwarded_for';

    server {
        listen 80;

        if ($time_iso8601 ~ "^(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})T(\d{2})") {
            set $year $1;
            set $month $2;
            set $day $3;
            set $hour $4;
        }

        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log main;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/healthd/application.log healthd; #works!
        access_log /var/log/nginx/healthd/application.log.$year-$month-$day-$hour healthd; #doesn't!

        location / {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

I thought this is a problem with dates, but I've printed them out using:

```
        location /temp {
            return 200 "/var/log/nginx/healthd/application.log.$year-$month-$day-$hour";
        }
```

and got back the correct string: `/var/log/nginx/healthd/application.log.2021-01-29-15`.

What might be causing this?

Comment: Here's a similar issue - https://serverfault.com/questions/762801/how-to-use-variables-in-access-log-filename-with-nginx-healthd
See if it helps?

Comment: @AntonDrukh wow thank you! It solved it! And what an unintuitive solution too.. Wanna add an actual answer and I'lll mark it correct?

Comment: No no, thanks! Please go ahead and answer yourself - there's a special badge for answering a question you yourself have asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The unintuivive (but correct) answer is described [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/762801/%E2%80%A6) and TLDR has to with this property of nginx:

> during each log write the existence of the request’s root directory is checked, and if it does not exist the log is not created.

Once you set the root directory that nginx can find, everything works as expected.

Thanks to @Anton Drukh for the link.